# How does the CD4066 Work?

Tags: audio

I am learning electronics so this is a beginners question. Its about the CD4066 IC as mentioned here

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/IC/4066

Is the 4066 equivalent to  four independently controllable  relays, where one relay switches on the pair X1,Y1?-Is this the purpose of this IC? So four relays are required to switch (the 4 pairs of audio signals)
X1,Y1

X2,Y2

X3,Y3

X4,Y4

Because in the IC there are four switches that can control the four pairs above. So with this IC 4 speakers are controllable by a digital CPU.

Comment: look at how much current & voltage you can switch - very limited. The chip is **not equivalent** to 4 relays.

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32413/digital-switching-for-audio. CD4066 can be used for audio, but the limitations (explained by Andy below) make it a bit difficult to work with. In particular, you have to ensure your signal is within the bounds of the CD4066 supply rails, which means either shifting the signal or having the audio ground inbetween the CD4066 supply rails.

Comment: Just one warning: there is no way you can switch the *speaker* signals with CD4066. If you want to use it to change your audio source, you should use the CD4066 *before* the amp and switch the input signal (which is low current).

Comment: @dim so if it was used to switch speaker signals it would have to be when the audio signal is less than 10ma and between the rail voltages accodring to andy aka's answer . Is that right?

Comment: You might be able to control *headphone* signals and you can certainly control line level audio signals, but definitely not speaker signals.

Comment: @Pete Yes, but I doubt the speaker signals are less than 10mA. In a typical 8ohm speaker, it means 0.8 milliWatts of power. Or maybe you like very very very quiet music. If you really want to switch *speaker* signals, use relays.

Comment: @dim how would you switch speaker signal at high frequency then? I mean faster than a relay.

Comment: Wait... Why do you want to switch that at high frequency? Ok, you have to explain what you want to achieve, here.

Comment: @dim it just a theoretical question to get a better understanding of electronics.

Comment: @dim I dont think transistors will work. So I wonder  how its done?

Comment: Well, then, I'll give you a good electronic advice: trying to do something unusual will typically be difficult to design. Switching high current speaker signals at high frequency is hard. Hopefully, it doesn't make sense. The world is well made, isn't it? Now, if you really wanted to do it, you'd certainly use some mosfets (it could be done with regular transistors too). But really, wasting time on this just "to get a better understanding of electronics" is useless. It is not trivial, so start by doing easier things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* regard the 4066 as 4 relay contacts but there are a bunch of constraints that limit this analogy. The main ones are: -

- On resistance is massively higher than a relay contact (typically 125 ohm)
- Ohmic linearity with input signal voltage means signal distortion may occur (unlike normal relay contacts).
- Any input / output signal must be constrained to the power rails of the device. In other words, there is *some" isolation capability that is useful but don't expect truly AC signals to do anything other than either badly distort or burn the chip.
- Maximum current is limited to a few mA
- Open circuit capacitance is quite high thus limiting the ability to "open-circuit" high speed signals.

Comment: So what the main purpose of this 4066 IC? Can it control 4 audio speakers with a CPU?

Comment: Main purpose is for switching low level analogue signals and, under all but the very lowest power applications, it cannot switch speaker signals (apart from the fact that speaker signals are AC as mentioned and this is a problem).

Comment: do you mean low voltage and power when you say  " low level analogue signals"

Comment: Any signals are basically constrained to be within the power rails so, if your power rails are 0 V and 5 volts then signals have to wholly be constrained within these limits with zero exceptions. Given the peak current is about 10 mA this means low power to me (125 ohms on resistance) but can also be low voltage or anything up to (say) 5 Vp-p.

Comment: Using the relay analogy- considering one pair x1,y1-when there is no signal to turn on the transmission gate-does this mean the resistance is zero between x1,y1?

Comment: You ought to read the data sheet. When the "relay" is on it is typically a resistance of 125 ohms. When it is off it is typically several Mohm. Don't confuse transmission gate signals (the signal being passed through the "contact") with the control signal (the signal used to turn on or off the "contact").

Comment: @Pete if you want more help with this may I suggest that you go back through the questions you've previously asked and, for each question, select the best answer and formally accept it. Some answers may not be answered to your satisfaction of course but, I suspect most are so, pay the debt of getting good EE information by playing the game.

Comment: Thank you but you probably should consider the other answers to your previous questions (hey that's what you are probably doing now).

Comment: You wrote " When it is off it is typically several Mohm. ". How would this Mohm value be typically used in an analog circuit?-I dont understand. I can understand the relay analogy though-it just means the relay is open between two points.

Comment: The Mohm value is a "weakness" - ideally (like in a relay contact) it would be infinite and not a few Mohms.

Answer (score 1):

These are not four relays but transmission gates.

The circuit (taken from [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf)) looks like this
[image]

As you can see the switch itself consists of two MOS transistors.

For details about the switching capabilities have a look at the datasheet.

Comment: So what the main purpose of this 4066 IC? Can it control 4 audio speakers with a CPU?